# Pass root all request of certain relative path to another directory using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, devops, virtualhost, litespeed

Below is example of directories and files in hosting

```
/MyDomainDotComDir/
../.htaccess
../Applications/
../othersDirInsideThisDomain/
../there-is-no-uploads-dir-here/

/MyCustomDir/
../uploads/

/OtherDomainDir/
```

**Currently**

if clients request on `mydomain.com/uploads/*` it will looking at `/home/myLinuxUsername/MyDomainDotComDir/uploads/`

__

**Question**

How to change or  pass it to find the files at `/home/myLinuxUsername/MyCustomDir/uploads/` instead of `/home/myLinuxUsername/MyDomainDotComDir/uploads/` **USING .htaccess**?

Server status:

- CentOs
- Shared hosting
- Server prodiver support told to me. I can't tweak Virtual Host because I'm on shared hosting

Comment: "_Server prodiver support told to me. I can't tweak Virtual Host because I'm on shared hosting_". Do you even have write access to anything outside of your vhost?

Comment: You could simply create a symlink in `MyDomainDotComDir` for the upload folder?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, they already  do that 2 times for 2 days (`ln -s ~/MyCustomDir/uploads/ ~/MyDomainDotComDir/uploads/`). But I don't know why is everyday in the morning I found that directory `~/MyDomainDotComDir/uploads/` is gone

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is posible because of `git checkout anotherBranch`? that's why I need to try another solution that might working for long term. Maybe .htaccess.

Comment: Why are you checking out other branches? I think you need to consider using a proper deployment flow, like using [deployer](https://deployer.org/) or similar.